# How does the word count program count hidden files?

Tags: linux

After creating a few directories and hidden files and running the following commands

```
ls -al | wc -l 
ls -a1 | wc -l
```

I get a difference in the total returned by the word count program. The

```
ls -al | wc -l
```

command returns one more count. Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ ls -al | head -n 1
total 57600
```

This line is not shown with `-1`.

Comment: Ignacio, I apologize but how does this help my question above?

Comment: Other than directly answering it?

Comment: What does your comment prove?

Comment: Maybe if the difference between `ls -al` and `ls -a1` were shown without piping to `wc` it would be clear to the OP why this answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

`|` is the pipe that connect the command, the output of left command `ls -al` is the input of right command `wc -l`.

output of command `ls -al` is string then `wc -l` will count the string as a file content,The file names in the string content isn't the argument for command `wc -l`.

the command `xargs` is useful,you can use it.
like:

```
ls -a | xargs wc -l
# find command to find files
find ./* | xargs wc -l
```